# Sort single entries by section with same query order

Tags: entries, order

When querying multiple singles by section slugs, is it possible to maintain the order of the results as the query?  Currently the return result is sorted by the default `postDate desc`.

```
craft.entries.section(['section1', 'section2', 'section3'])
```

returns an array with the order
section1, section2, section3

Documentation doesn't seem to answer this question.
https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible with the `id` parameter in combination with [`fixedOrder`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#fixedOrder).

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.id([307, 287, 488]).fixedOrder(true) %}
```

You can look up your singles' IDs in the URL of the entries in the CP.

example.com/admin/entries/section1/**307**-section1/

Comment: Thanks!  Worked perfectly!  Should have looked at the docs better :)